# Last icon glued in the edge - cell screen

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, row, responsive

Please see my code:
http://clubedebeneficiosunilife.com.br/categorias.php

what I need ?
I need this bar this orange style that displays 13 icons but stay harmonics. That is, stay centered horizontally as well as vertically. Note that if I open my link (http://clubedebeneficiosunilife.com.br/categorias.php) on smaller screens, the result is ugly. The 13th icon opens practically glued to the edge of the orange bar.

Studying bootstrapping, I saw that there may be 12 columns. But as I have 13 icons, that complicated to me.

I'm new in the bootstrap, someone could help me to display these 13 icons symmetrically this orange bar?

Thank you and thank you very much!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: the example is on the link:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want to have.

Add a class like I did (mydiv for example) on the wrapping div:

```
<div class = "col-sm-6 col-md-12 mydiv">
   ...
</div>
```

Then add this to your stylesheets (mydiv is the example class i used):

```
.mydiv {
  display:table;
}

.mydiv a {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yzen382o/

Your Responsive-Problem is fixed here:
https://jsfiddle.net/x9omqm1c/

Comment: thanks for the help, really was aligned. But it is not responsive. I need the 'come down' icons on smaller screens so that it is responsive!

Comment: I added a second fiddle for your second task (responsive), which was new to me.

Comment: Thanks ... Excellent result!